# Colaboratory - Remember Google Drive Auth (Python)

Tags: python, authentication, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm working on a Python (3.6) project using Google Colaboratory notebook and I need to access files on Google Drive. Using the code below I can read files on Drive but it asks for a security code each time the code block is run, so whenever the session times-out I need to get the security code again.

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Is there a better and more convenient way to do this? Constant authentication is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using PyDrive. [PyDrive](https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html) is a wrapper library of [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) that simplifies many common Google Drive API tasks.

The snippet below is a snippet from [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk). It demonstrates the authentication part of the code.

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

If you need more examples, you can visit the [PyDrive documentation](https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html).

Comment: Cheers thanks! I should spend a bit of time getting to know PyDrive better.